# Cannot edit entities in admin view of Google Apps Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am working on a java project on Google app engine and when I go to admin I am not able to edit the entities. I can view them though. I am on windows xp and developing in eclipse. Let me know if you need any more info to help me make these entities editable.

> http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=User

Edit: I have installed appwrench to edit in eclipse but its giving java.IO.ioexception and then says "Unable to detect local development server"

The application works fine otherwise ie., without the appwrench.

Comment: Hm, looks really strange, may you post me a stack trace of those exception?

Regards,
Pavel

Comment: Our (AppWrench development) team would gladly help you resolve the IO exception problem. Please get in touch and e-mail your Eclipse log to support@appwrench.zendesk.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it works fine, I need to stat localserver first and then the appwrench.